# Coloring Bar Graph in Excel based on value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I have the following data

```
 Client              Week            Revenue

 Google              1               4000
 Microsoft           1               5000
 Intel               2               2000
 EvilCorporation     3               1000
```

You get the idea (the numbers and names have obviously been changed in the above data).  I want the bar graph to be a certain color based on the week number. The data will change week to week, but there will always be a week 1, 2 and 3. So i need 3 colors, one for each week, that corresponds to the proper company. The x-values would label the companies, and Y values would be the revenue.

From my research, I found out that this is pretty much impossible in excel using the graph tools, and VBA is required. While I do know VBA functions, I have 0 experience with VBA graphing, and how and where would you call the function after creating it.

If there is a different type of graph this would be easier with, I'm all for it, as long as it is easy to look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a table in Excel as you provided (in A1:C5):

1. Select the range of your data in worksheet (i.e. A1:C5).
2. Open 'Microsoft Visual Basic® for Applications' (Press `ALT + F11` in
   Excel).
3. Create a new module on your current excel file project (Right click
   your VBA project > Insert > Module).
4. Paste the following code.
5. Run the code (Press `F5`).
6. Go back to your worksheet. Done!!!

Following code will help you to: create the bar chart and formatting the color according to the 'week' value.

```
Sub CreateChartFormattingbyPtValue()

Set rRng = Selection

'SET YOUR DESIRED COLOR HERE
week1ColorIndex = 3
week2ColorIndex = 4
week3ColorIndex = 5

'Chart Basic Setting
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=rRng
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlBarClustered
ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)

'Force to create dummy Series to present Legend (Week value with color)
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).Name = "=""Week 1"""
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Name = "=""Week 2"""
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=""Week 3"""
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = ThisWorkbook.Colors(week3ColorIndex)
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = ThisWorkbook.Colors(week2ColorIndex)
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = ThisWorkbook.Colors(week1ColorIndex)

'Size and Position of Chart
With ActiveChart.Parent
    .Height = 400
    .Width = 500
    .Top = 150
    .Left = 150
End With

'Axes label font size italic and bold
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.Font.Size = 10
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.Font.Bold = False
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.Font.Italic = True

'Chart Title
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Your Title Here (Week1:Red , Week2:Green , Week3:Green)"
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Font.Size = 12


With ActiveChart
    vX = .SeriesCollection(1).XValues
    vY = .SeriesCollection(1).Values

    'Formatting the interior color for each points
    For thisvY = 1 To UBound(vY)
        If vY(thisvY) = 1 Then .SeriesCollection(2).Points(thisvY).Interior.ColorIndex = week1ColorIndex
        If vY(thisvY) = 2 Then .SeriesCollection(2).Points(thisvY).Interior.ColorIndex = week2ColorIndex
        If vY(thisvY) = 3 Then .SeriesCollection(2).Points(thisvY).Interior.ColorIndex = week3ColorIndex
    Next thisvY

End With


End Sub
```

Remarks:

1. Remember to select the range of your data in worksheet before run.
2. This code is customized according to your data table. You can add
   new row as necessary, but if you modify the column order then you
   need to modify the code too.
3. If you want to change the week color, you just need to change the `ColorIndex`
   number at the beginning of the code: `week1ColorIndex`, `week2ColorIndex`, `week3ColorIndex`.
4. If you want to adjust the size or font, look into `Height`,
   `Width`, `.Font.Size`.
5. Code has been tested OK on Win 7 Office 2010.

Comment: Thank you...would never have been able to write that code...too many rules and formatting / syntax stuff that I never learned

Comment: I am wondering how i would add a legend, I notice the (msoElementLegendNone), which I am assuming turns off the legend. I would like the legend to say Week1, Week2, Week3, in the color of the weeks (i changed them to 6. 46. 3..Yellow, Orange Red)

Comment: For legend issue and size problem you mentioned before, I have modified the code adding those what you need: chart size, font size, enable legend, color settings. Try it. And if you want other chart setting, I think you can easily find out the VBA syntax through insite searching.

Comment: once again thank you. It worked great, and I can also understand more of this VBA style code (as opposed to function vbas, which is what I am used to).

Answer (score 1):

I think it's impossible without VBA. A simple "MIX" can be this.
Following the scheme:

[image]

The column "B" have the Conditional formatting to Set the color you want in the graph. If you don't want see, copy the value (reference) to another column hidden...
In the VBA Manager ad the code below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim yy

    yy = ActiveCell.Address
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    i = 1
    For Each xx In ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points
        i = i + 1
        xx.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = Range("B" & i).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color   ' REF
    Next
    Range(yy).Activate
End Sub
```

To open VBA Manager use ALT+F11, after double click on Sheet1 (On the left) and paste the code...
If you have the same scheme in the sheet, it's not a problem. If you have other range change the line with REF, changing the column of the week...
The best way is TRY !!!

Comment: I am unsure whether or not this will work, simply because I used the other commenters answer first. I just wanted to thank you for putting in the time to help me out...I am going to tinker with this to see which of the solutions I like better. But just wanted to comment this to let you know how much I appreciate all the help.

Comment: How do you run this code to actually put the graph in, I opened the module and pasted it in, i tried f5 as i did with the other solution, but that didn't work. Sorry, I am kind of new to VBA, my experience is only in creating functions.

Comment: Not indise a Module. Like I have write, you need to put INDISE the sheet you have the chart. For example in Sheet1. After it works automatically. When you change something (for example the week number) it autoupdate the chart...

Comment: @user3514930 Would you mind explaining this in more concrete steps? It's an interesting approach but you're skipping steps which makes your answer not clear.